# Best way to convert text file

Tags: vb.net, converters

I am trying to make a conversion program which converts multiple text files from a cad design file into a file that the machine can read.

each file has multiple values and is laid out like this:

```
X             -0.0001
Y              1.0500
Z              1.5700

LOCATION       0.0050
```

Each file stands for a location that the machine is supposed to go to and do something. The output needs to look something like this:

```
X-0.0001Y1.0500Z1.5700L0.0050
Other information regarding position is here also.
```

so it's a fairly simple conversion. But what I'm wondering is what the best way to go about it is. Do I convert each file individually then combine them? The other information has to go at the bottom of the file. So where there are more files it would go:

```
Location 1
Location 2
Location 1 parameters
location 2 parameters
```

I have tried a couple different ways and still cannot come up with the best way to do it.

essentially what I'm asking is what the best/ most efficient way would be to convert these files. Sorry if this is confusing.

Note I am using vb.net for the programming language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is a project of enormous scale (e.g. millions of files), you might want to look into something like [map reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_reduce).

if not (which I'm guessing), I would suggest as follows:

parse each file sequentially, adding (appending)the results to each of TWO files.  Finally, combine the two files and you're done.

LOCATIONS_FILE (FILE 1)

```
Location 1
Location 2
(etc)
```

METADATA_FILE (FILE 2)

```
location 1 params
location 2 params
(etc)
```

when all files are parsed, append the contents of FILE 2 to those of FILE 1.

FINAL FILE

```
Location 1
Location 2
(etc)
location 1 params
location 2 params
(etc)
```

I don't use VB.NET.  But, pseudocode would be something like:

```
fn parse_file(file,locations_filehandle, metadata_filehandle):
    file.extract_locations() -> append(locations_filehandle)
    file.extract_metadata() -> append(metadata_filehandle)

fn main():
   for file in files:
      parse_file(file,locations_filehandle,metadata_filehandle)

   finalfile=locations_filehandle.read() + metadata_filehandle.read()
   finalfile.writeToDisk()


main()
```